# Do browsers understand viewport on its own?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I have two files as follows

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>   
  </body>
</html>
```

*index2.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>  
  </body>
</html>
```

The above two html documents behave the same way when I change the size of the browser window. What is the `viewport` meta name achieving in the second document?
I have seen bootstrap documents using the meta tag as in the second document with all its css and js files. What is the advantage bootstrap gets by using it in that manner?

**EDIT**

For some reason the desktop browsers show the same behaviour for the above two documents,but when I used a mobile broswer (safari in an iphone) I saw the difference of those two documents. The second document resized its contents matching the device width.

Answer (score 0):

It is because that Bootstrap uses `viewport` tag to optimize its stylesheet for mobile browsers. You can try to change the value of `viewport` of your HTML, open the page with Chrome simulator and have a look.

And it's better to read these documents about viewport:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
- http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html , http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Comment: does it mean that viewport does not have to do anything with responsive web design?

Comment: @DesirePRG in my opinion, viewport is a basic setting for the responsive web design.

Comment: but how did the text in the first document automatically position itself without the viewport property(when resizing the window).